# How to actually execute CoreData heavyweight migration

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am performing a CoreData heavyweight migration in my app. I have created a mapping model, made associated NSEntityMigrationPolicy subclasses, and selected the new model as the current. However, the migration does not appear to be happening. What do I need to do for this to actually occur?

Answer (score 0):

If your model is not eligible for lightweight migration, then you have to do it manually. Simply this process can explained as reading records from old store and dumping them in the new store according to new model.

See [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-migration/) and [here](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-migrations-swift-tutorial/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually switch off the automatic migrations from persistent store coordinator so core data would not automatically infer mapping model and use your custom created model in core data stack.

```
key: NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption
value: false
```